# how to break or continue a loop from user input

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a code that loops when y is entered and stops when n is entered, this is what I have so far.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
do{ 
    System.out.println("She sells seashells by the seashore.");
    System.out.println("Do you want to hear it again?");
}while (input.hasNext());{
input.hasNext("y");
   }
```

I have no clue how to continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For more readable code you can use a boolean variable and assign it to true according to **your input equals to "y"** condition

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean stopFlag= false;
        do{
            System.out.println("She sells seashells by the seashore.");
            System.out.println("Do you want to hear it again?");
            String userInput =input.next();
            if(!userInput.equals("y"))
                stopFlag=true;
        }while (!stopFlag);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
while(input.hasNext()) {
    String temp = input.next();
    if(temp.equals("y")) {
        // if you need to do something do it here
        continue; // will go to the next iteration
    } else if(temp.equals("n")) {
        break; // will exit the loop
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are persistent on using do...while then you can try:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
do{ 
    System.out.println("She sells seashells by the seashore.");
    System.out.println("Do you want to hear it again?");
}while (input.hasNext() && !input.next().equals("n"));
```

Comment: This will not repeat loop if user enters `y`. In fact, it will repeat only if user didn't enter `y`.

Comment: You can change the second condition in accordance with the requirement but the logic still holds. You can convert that to `!input.next().equals("n")` and continue for all the other cases.

Comment: Your current answer is doing exact opposite of what OP asked for.

Comment: I've changed it to break for input = "n". But the question is still very ambiguous since it says continue on "y", break on "n". and what if something else is entered.